# How to convert a fake server from Sinon to Jasmine.

Tags: javascript, jasmine, sinon

I found an example how to create a fake server using Sinon.
Here is the code (1), (2).

It will be possible to make the same thing using just Jasmine?
If yes. How should I rewrite the code (1) and (2) ?

---

(1)

```
        beforeEach(function () {
            this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
            this.server.respondWith(
                'GET',
                Routing.generate('api_get_url') + '/' + this.model.get('id'),
                JSON.stringify(this.fixtureResponse)
            );
        });
```

---

(2)

```
        it('should the response not change', function() {
            this.model.fetch();
            this.server.respond();
            expect(this.fixtureResponse).toEqual(this.model.attributes);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how your code is accessing the server, but if it's using jQuery's `$.ajax` or `$.get` (or something similarly centralized) the way Backbone does, you can stub that out and return fake responses instead.  So #1 would look roughly like this, in CoffeeScript:

```
spyOn($,'get').andCallFake (options) =>
  if options.url == Routing.generate('api_get_url') + '/' + @model.get('id')
    options.success(JSON.stringify @fixtureResponse)
```

See also: [Preventing AJAX call with Jasmine and Sinon using Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550926/preventing-ajax-call-with-jasmine-and-sinon-using-backbone)