# Preventing AJAX call with Jasmine and Sinon using Backbone

Tags: unit-testing, backbone.js, coffeescript, jasmine, sinon

I'm just getting started testing my Backbone app with Sinon and Jasmine.  I have a view that look something like (coffeescript):

```
  initialize: ->
    @collection.on 'reset', @render, this

  render: ->
    if @collection.fetched
      # do stuff
    else
      @$el.append "<h3>Loading...</h3>"

      @collection.fetch()

    this
```

I want to test this with an unfetched collection, but I'm not sure how to fake an ajax call within my code (obviously can easily be done in the spec).  I realize that I could just pass in a pre-fetched collection, but I'm curious -- is it possible with Sinon to override the fetch function to return a fake response?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the hood, Backbone uses jQuery's `$.ajax` method, so you can stub that out.  We use this to catch accidental calls in our Jasmine specs:

```
$.ajax = -> throw "ajaxShouldBeStubbedOutError: #{JSON.stringify arguments}"
```

And then you can stub over that if you want to fake an AJAX call and its response:

```
spyOn($,'ajax').andCallFake (options) =>
  if options.url is "/correct"
    options.success {"data":"yay"}
```